# WHILE loop for the LIST

Tags: list, while-loop, sml

I need to write a very simple function in SML. It should check if the value 'elem' is greater than any value of the field 'f1' in the list 'L'. The list 'L' contains 3 fields - 'f1','f2','f3'. The function should return 1 if the statement 'elem>f1' is true for any of the members of the list 'L'. Otherwise, the function should return 0. For instance:

```
L = 
f1 f2 f3
1  4  6
2  1  2
3  4  8
8  5  9

elem = 3

fun check(L: myList, elem: int): int =
let
  val counter = ref 0
  val counter_end = length L
in
       while (!counter <= counter_end) do
            let val f1 = List.nth(L,counter) 
            in
               if elem > f1 then 1 else 0
            end
            counter := !counter + 1 
end
```

I don't know how to get the field 'f1' from the list 'L'. Any ideas are HIGHLY appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a while loop? That's generally an awful idea in SML.

Comment: Well, I'm just newbie in SML, and therefore I have no other idea of how to solve my problem. But if you know other solution, please describe it here. Thx.

Comment: what should the function return? And what should happen if no member of the list has `elem > f1`?

Comment: If the statement 'elem>f1' is true for any of the entries in 'L', then the function should return 1. Otherwise it should return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SML (and functional languages in general), you'll typically want to rely on recursion rather than imperative constructs like loops.

I'm a bit rusty in SML, but here's one way to  define the function

```
fun check elem [] = 0
  | check elem ((f1,f2,f3)::tl) = if elem > f1 then 1 else check elem tl;
```

It can then be called like this:

```
(* define a list to scan *)
val L = [(1,4,6),(2,1,2),(3,4,8),(8,5,9)];
(* call the function on our list *)
check 3 L;
```

The function is defined recursively, using pattern matching: The first line says that if the function is called on an empty list, the result is zero.
The second line says that if it is called on a list, where the first element is the tuple `(f1,f2,f3)`, then the result is 1 if `elem > f1`, and otherwise, it's the result of invoking the function recursively on the tail of the list

Also note that I omitted the type specifiers. You rarely need them, because the language infers the types automatically. The compiler already knows which types can be safely used with the code you wrote, so why bother telling it what types you think the arguments are going to be?

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive function instead of using a loop. (And it would probably make more sense to use a boolean return instead of an integer.)

Easiest way to extract the fields is via pattern matching in the argument list. Assuming your three fields are in a tuple, something like this:

```
fun check((f1,f2,f3)::L: myList, elem: int)
```